# How does jQuery deserialize JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, json

I am using jQuery.ajax(...) to retrieve JSON data from an ASP.NET MVC service. When the server encounters an exception, I send a 400 Bad Request status back to the client and send my exception as a JsonResult:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
return Json(new { ex.Message, ex.StackTrace });
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: deleteUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    data:
    {
        dataItems: dataItems,
        toJSON: true
    },
    success: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg[i].dataItem);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error)
    {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

My ASP.NET code sends me to the error section of my JavaScript code, and the error block only allows me to read the request.responseText rather than work with the objects returned from the server.

Now, rather than add in yet another JavaScript include to something like [json_parse](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js) and simply deserialize my Exception, I'd like to simply leverage the same JSON parser that jQuery uses, though I can't find readily find information on it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I found a post (http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx) on Rick Strahl's blog that explains:

"Note that the ajaxJSON function requires JSON encoding. jQuery doesn't have any native JSON encoding functionality (which seems a big omission, but was probably done to preserve the small footprint). However there are a number of JSON implementations available. Above I'm using the JSON2.js file from Douglas Crockford to serialize the parameter object map into JSON."

I thought I had read this changed in jQuery 1.4...

Comment: what changed was jQuery will now use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval` if it is available. jQuery never provided (and still does not provide) OOTB support for JSON *serialization*.

Comment: @Crescent, that should be given as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Cheeso: it's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery used to use `eval`, if I'm not mistaken. Since 1.4, it takes advantage of native JSON deserializer if there is any (there is one in Firefox, for instance)

Comment: Anyone know if jQuery exposed a handy method for this?

Comment: @Peder: yes, `jQuery.httpData(request, "json")` will give you back your parsed JSON/JavaScript object.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to specify "json"; httpData will default to that.

Answer (score 2):

i think in javascript if you have a json string you can use eval to get an object, ie:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

there is more information about this on http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Not the safest way to parse data.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said. Since in this case I'm only bringing back "safe" data and not user-provided data, I can safely deserialize the request data using eval.

Comment: In `$.ajax` error function, you can then use : `function (xhr) { json = eval('('+xhr.responseText+')'); ... };`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you. I use it to delete comments and spaces in my json :

```
json = eval( o.responseText
    .replace( /\/\*(.*)\*\/g, ' ' )
    .replace( /([^\:])\/\/[^\n]*\n/g, '$1' )
    .replace( /^\s|\s+|\s$/g, '' ) )
```

Comment: Comments aren't legal JSON anyway. Why are they being returned in your response?