# JSON de-serializing using jquery in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am getting JSON response through jquery/Ajax in my django template as follows:

```
[{"total_count": {"3": 1}, "all_user_request": [{"pk": 3, "model": "new_tracker.new_request", "fields": {"status": "Open", "severity": "High", "title": "New Year wish", "last_modified_date": "05-01-2012", "creation_date": "05-01-2012", "priority": "High", "department": "IT", "primary_assignee": "John", "creator": "Martin", "description": "Martin has requested on Thu Jan 05 2012 18:19:53:<br />Happy new year"}}]}]
```

Now I want to de-serialize it using Jquery. Can anyone help me to achieve this ? Till now, I tried like this but with no luck,

```
success: function( all_user_request ){
$.each( all_user_request, function( key, value ){
             request_id = value.all_user_request.pk;
             total_count = value.total_count.request_id;
status = value.all_user_request.fields.status;
........code follows like this
```

please let me know if the information is incomplete. I have used simplejson.dumps while serializing.

Thanks in advance,
Sunil

Comment: let us see the actual javascript where you actually make the request.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but it looks like you are trying to loop over a dictionary when you really have a dictionary/object inside an array of size 1.

Comment: may be this is going to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112831/how-does-jquery-deserialize-json

Comment: javascript console, console.log() and js debugger (breakpoints, ...) can help you a lot here ;)

Answer (score 0):

the parsing of the json should happen at the point of the request.

jQuery does this automatically, as long as you specify `'json'` as your dataType.